# how to work out percentage from two variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, percentage

I have two variables that are counting the amount of times two functions are being run. I was wondering whether there is anyway I could work out a percentage from these and then display it on the page?

for example

var win = 10;
var lose = 10;

percentage would be 50% but unsure how to do this with javascript?

Comment: Did you take arithmetic in grade school? Divide one of the numbers by the sum of the numbers and multiply by 100.

Comment: I think this is off-topic, because it is a very basic math question.

Answer (score 1):

Divide one of the numbers by the total:

```
var winPercent = win/(win+lose)*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a Maths, not a Javascript question ;)

```
var winPercentage = 100 * win / (win + lose);
var losePercentage = 100 * lose / (win + lose);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
win + lose = 100%
```

Right ?

Then the win percentage would be :

```
(win / (win + lose))*100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more to do with maths than js... Anyway:

```
var percentage = win / (win + lose) * 100;
```